# AngularJS: Using ControllerAs in router not working and Issue with app.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Could someone please point out the mistakes in the code,

**Problem 1** Save button of addstudent.html file is not working. If using $Scope then its working but have modified the code for using ControllerAs, the functionality stopped working. When checked in debugger tool even control is not comimg in addStudentController page at line

**(addCtrl.saveStudent = function(student){)**

on clicking save button and nothing is happening.

**Problem 2** In app.js when ever the commented code become active, the application stopped working at all.

**Problem 3** Want to know the way of redirecting to index.html at cancel button of addStudentController.js, using window.location is good practice?

addStudentController.js

```
module.controller('addStudentController',
        function addStudentController(){    
          addCtrl = this;
          addCtrl.saveStudent = function(student){
              window.alert(student.name+' save successfully');
          };
          addCtrl.cancelStudent = function(){
              window.location='/index';
          };
        }       
);
```

app.js

```
var module = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider    
    /*.when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'studentController',
        title: 'This is index page'
    })*/
    .when('/addStudent', {
        templateUrl:'templates/addStudent.html',
        controller:'addStudentController',
        controllerAs: 'addCtrl'
    })
    /*.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    })*/;
}]);
```

addStudent.html

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>New Student</h1>
        <p>
            <img data-ng-src="{{student.imageUrl}}" alt={{student.name}}
                height="40px">
        </p>
        <hr>
        <form name="newStudentForm">
            <fieldset>

                    <label for="studentName">Student Name:</label> 
                    <input id="studentName" type="text" data-ng-model="student.name" required
                    placeholder="Name of student...."> <br>

                    <label for="studentDepartment">Student Department:</label> 
                    <input id="studentDepartment" type="text"
                    data-ng-model="student.department" placeholder="Name of student Department ...."> <br>

                    <label for="studentBranch">Student Branch:</label> 
                    <input id="studentBranch" type="text" data-ng-model="student.branch"
                    placeholder="Name of student Branch ...."> <br>

            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="newStudentForm.$invalid"
                data-ng-click="saveStudent(student)">Save</button>

            <button type="button" data-ng-click="cancelStudent()">
                Cancel</button>

        </form>
        <label for="studentImage">Student Image:</label> <input
            id="studentImage" type="text" data-ng-model="student.imageUrl"
            placeholder="url for student image ...."> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Use addCtrl.saveStudent(student) in your html

Problem 2: Do you see an exception in the console? You might not have injected the controller correctly, or your template url could be wrong. Hard to tell with current info.

Problem 3: Use location service: [Angular location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)